# MySQL dump ignores full DB views create statement

Tags: mysql

--> I've MySQL DB running v5.7.40

```
mysql> SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'version';
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| Variable_name | Value                       |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
| version       | 5.7.40-0ubuntu0.18.04.1-log |
+---------------+-----------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql>
```

--> Currently doing backup of one of the DBs using mysqldump

```
root@reporting:~# cat /var/scripts/backup.sh
#!/bin/bash
.
.
.
backup(){
    DBASE="jiradbrepl"
    mysqldump -u root $DBASE  >/storage/backup/$DBASE-$MONTH_DAY.sql
}
root@reporting:~#
```

--> The backup completes without any errors or warnings but it doesn't include full create statement of DB views

```
root@reporting:~# bash  /var/scripts/backup.sh
++ hostname -s
+ MY_HOSTNAME=reporting
++ date +%b-%d
+ MONTH_DAY=Jan-15
+ backup
+ DBASE=jiradbrepl
+ mysqldump -u root jiradbrepl
+ cleanup
+ find /storage/backup/ -type f -name '*.sql' -mtime +5 -exec rm '{}' ';'
root@reporting:~#
```

```
root@reporting:~# ls -lh /storage/backup/jiradbrepl-Jan-15.sql
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 748M Jan 15 14:37 /storage/backup/jiradbrepl-Jan-15.sql
root@reporting:~#
```

--> For example this view stops at the middle of the creation statement

```
root@reporting-db:~# less /storage/backup/jiradbrepl-Jan-15.sql
.
.
.
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `V_R_PROJECTS_BIRDEYE`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `V_R_PROJECTS_BIRDEYE`*/;
SET @saved_cs_client     = @@character_set_client;
SET character_set_client = utf8;
/*!50001 CREATE VIEW `V_R_PROJECTS_BIRDEYE` AS SELECT
 1 AS `projectName`,
 1 AS `CPID`,
 1 AS `GEO`,
 1 AS `region`,
 1 AS `subRegion`,
 1 AS `startDate`,
 1 AS `endDate`,
 1 AS `status`,
 1 AS `LOE`,
 1 AS `discountedLOE`,
 1 AS `status_history`,
 1 AS `prjPoCName`,
 1 AS `ML_CQ`,
 1 AS `BC_CQ`,
 1 AS `commitedBudget`,
 1 AS `URL`,
 1 AS `prjActualDays`,
 1 AS `prjPendingDays`,
 1 AS `prjPlannedDays`,
 1 AS `currentQuarterActualDays`,
 1 AS `currentQuarterPendingDays`,
 1 AS `remainingQuarterPlannedDays`,
 1 AS `currentQuarterPlannedDays`,
 1 AS `nextQuarterPlannedDays`,
 1 AS `PSO_PM`,
 1 AS `COE_PM`,
 1 AS `techList`,
 1 AS `budgetActuals`,
 1 AS `budgetForecast`,
 1 AS `budgetPlanned`*/;
SET character_set_client = @saved_cs_client;
root@reporting-db:~#
```

--> The backup runs with root user which has all privileges

```
mysql> show grants for root;
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for root@%                                           |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'root'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION |
+-------------------------------------------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

```
root@reporting-db:~# mysql -ANe"SELECT USER(),CURRENT_USER()"
+----------------+----------------+
| root@localhost | root@localhost |
+----------------+----------------+
root@reporting-db:~#
```

--> I've tried running the backup using the command in [Views not being dumped by mysqldump](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9491964/views-not-being-dumped-by-mysqldump)
--> Also using this command but that didn't help

```
mysqldump -u root --lock-tables --comments --dump-date --force --events --routines --add-drop-table --add-locks --log-error=/tmp/jiradbreplbackup.log jiradbrepl  > /storage/backup/jiradbrepl-Jan-15_2.sql
```

```
root@reporting-db:~# cat /tmp/jiradbreplbackup.log
root@reporting-db:~#
```

Please let me know if you have any suggestion for this issue.

Comment: Is this answer your question : https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/11004/will-mysqldump-command-also-backup-all-the-views-that-are-present-in-db-or-there

Comment: Please ask database admin related wuestions on the dedicated DBA sister site of SO!

Comment: Do you see two definitions in the dump file for your view, one headed "Temporary view structure" and the second one headed "Final view structure"? See https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/client/mysqldump.c#L2557

Answer (score 1):

If you look further down in your dump file, you'll see the view is created a second time in a format that will look more complete. The name of the view is first created as a temporary table (that create statement is what you've shown above) in case other views depend on it (ref https://github.com/twitter-forks/mysql/blob/master/client/mysqldump.c#L2557). Then it is created as a view with the full create statement you expect. Here is an example.

Given this table:

```
create table mytable (id int, firstname varchar(50), lastname varchar(50));
```

And this view on that table:

```
create view myview as select id, firstname from mytable;
```

Do a dump of the database:

```
mysqldump -u user -ppassword mydatabase  >/tmp/dump.sql
```

Resulting dump file:

```
cat /tmp/dump.sql
-- MySQL dump 10.13  Distrib 8.0.31, for macos13.0 (x86_64)
...

--
-- Table structure for table `mytable`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `mytable`; 
...
CREATE TABLE `mytable` (
  `id` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `firstname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `lastname` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci; 
...

--
-- Dumping data for table `mytable`
--

...

--
-- Temporary view structure for view `myview`
--

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `myview`;
/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `myview`*/;
...
/*!50001 CREATE VIEW `myview` AS SELECT
 1 AS `id`,
 1 AS `firstname`*/;

...

--
-- Final view structure for view `myview`
--

/*!50001 DROP VIEW IF EXISTS `myview`*/;
...
/*!50001 CREATE ALGORITHM=UNDEFINED */
/*!50013 DEFINER=`user`@`localhost` SQL SECURITY DEFINER */
/*!50001 VIEW `myview` AS select `mytable`.`id` AS `id`,`mytable`.`firstname` AS `firstname` from `mytable` */;
...

-- Dump completed on 2023-01-17  7:40:31
```